# Python Cryptography run time error on _init_cffi_1_0_external_module

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography

installing cryptography:

successfully installed gcc, libffi-devel on python 2.7.

When i try executing the script getting the below error:

> > > from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/fernet.py", line 17, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
> > >         File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py", line 13, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
> > >       AttributeError: _init_cffi_1_0_external_module

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you installed it, with which python, on what operating system, when getting this error?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1484870/comments/2

Comment: And see [python - pip fails with AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_init_cffi_1_0_external_module' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54054263/507544)